# Echo Dropdown Value into readonly input

Tags: php, jquery

Good day! I have a problem getting the value of the drop down select input and echo the value to the readonly input without reloading the web browser.

The dropdown select input values comes from Product which has Product_id attributes and Unit_values but I don't know how to get the Unit_values value into Product_id dropdown select if selected.

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Product</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" id="inputSmall" name="product" required >
                        option readonly  hidden value="">-- Select a Product --</option>
                            <?php while($row1 = $product->fetch_object()):  ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row1->Product_ID; ?>">
                            <?php echo $row1->Product_Description ?></option>
                            <?php endwhile ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Unit Value:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                        <input type="text" readonly placeholder="Unit Value" id="qty" 
name="quantity" class="form-control" value="<?php  ?>"><span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code? what have you tried so far? what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to read the text() property of selected option and assign it to value of input field, like this:

```
$('#inputSmall').on('change', function(){
    let unitVal = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $('#qty').val(unitVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need use AJAX (usually using jQuery) to look at Data Base. But I guess that the best solution is create the options with Unit_values already setted like using data attribute.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" id="inputSmall" name="product" required >
                    option readonly  hidden value="">-- Select a Product --</option>
                        <?php while($row1 = $product->fetch_object()):  ?>
                        <option data-unit-values="<?php echo $row1->Unit_values; ?>" value="<?php echo $row1->Product_ID; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row1->Product_Description ?></option>
                        <?php endwhile ?>
                </select>
```

If you do like this it's just to get data value using jQuery.

```
$("select").data("unit-values");
```